# Network Time Protocol

Tags: distributed-system

In a distributed system two nodes A and B want to synchronize their clocks.
The communications delay along the link A to B is 40ms and along B to A is 20 ms.

These delays are unknown to A and B.
These nodes use Cristian's algorithm to synchronize their clocks.
Node A's clock is 500 ms and  B's clock is 632ms.

And the node A is initiator. After completion, what is the time that A shows?

Comment: It shows how little time you spent trying to figure it out yourself. [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a very academic question.
In practice, it is the variance in the delay that is the problem, not the latency. However, the rule is that you can only see the RTT (Round Trip Time) which is 60ms. Both sides will assume that the delay is a 30ms/30ms split. This means that one side will have a clock 10ms too fast and one 10ms too slow.

Comment: Yes, it's a question in our exams. The answer is 702. I can't figure out how 702 is correct.

Comment: Hmm, it's easy to see where the figure comes from, A asks B for the time, the RTT=60, so the reply arrives at 692. A adjusts it by half the RTT (10) = 702. (It's 10 because the reply took 20s, but A estimates 30s)

Comment: A tags the time it sent the message (normally in the message itself). B replies with a message with it's time, but includes the time the message was sent on A. A then subtracts the time when the packet arrived, from the time it was sent (and gets 60ms). This always works because both times are from A.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Sorry but I sill didn't get the half RTT(10), since you said RTT is 60?

Comment: A can see the RTT is 60ms, but doesn't know the split A->B vs B->A. It assumes the split is even (30/30ms), but really it's 20ms, 30-20 is 10

Comment: here the one-way delays are unkown to A ad B, how does A knows the real delay is 40, so 10 should be added to 692 at the end. Here we just assume the network latency is symmetric in both directions?